# Creating a font with just a few characters

Tags: android

Not even sure how to phrase the subject line properly, but what I want to do is this:

I want to use a few special characters in my app, e.g. x̄, which are not in the system's built-in font.

I could simply define my own ttf font with the specific characters in it, but I'd like the system font to be used for everything else.

Is there a way to specify a "fail-over" font?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/)

Answer (score 0):

It need to load this font library by yourself,then,set the displayed font.
It can be changed only when run.

```
Typeface.createFromAsset(xxxxxx)
TextView.setTypeface(xxxx)
```

Comment: Yes, this part I know.  But what I want to do is create a font with just the x̄ character in it, and have the system use the default font for everything else.

Comment: @EdwardFalk that need you to change DroidSansFallback font library by yourself

Comment: You mean make a copy of Droid Sans and add the missing character(s)?  Won't that require a huge amount of space?  I suppose I could delete the characters I don't use.

Comment: No,use the font editing software to modify the file 'DroidSansFallback. TTF'